# bash - Why does the "-e" at the beginning of my variable not get output with echo?

Tags: string, bash, set

At the command prompt ($) I execute the commands:

```
$ stupid="-a hello"
$ echo $stupid
```

Echo produces:

```
-a hello
```

At the command prompt ($) I execute the commands:

```
$ stupid="-e hello"
$ echo $stupid
```

Echo produces:

```
hello
```

Why did the "-e" disappear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `$stupid` is unquoted, it gets processed as flag of `echo` and enables interpretation of backslash escapes.

If you did:

```
$ stupid="-e hello"
$ echo "$stupid"
```

You would see value of `$stupid` echoed in its entirety:

```
-e hello
```

Because the resulting command after variable expansion would be

```
echo "-e hello"
```

In your case however, `$stupid` is first expanded and then then the command is executed as:

```
echo -e hello
```

It may become even more obvious if your variable value actually included an escaped character such as: `foo="-e \ttext"`, try both `echo $foo` and `echo "$foo"` and see what happens.

Bottom line: double quoting your strings and or variable is usually the prudent thing to do.

Comment: Note that none of this is portable; for example, some versions of `echo` will *always* print the "-e" literally. If you want reliable results, use `printf` instead, e.g. `printf '%s\n' "$stupid"`. But note that the double-quotes are required, or it'll treat the value of `stupid` as multiple strings, and print each one on a separate line rather than splicing them back together like `echo` does. Double-quotes are almost always a good idea, it's just more obvious here.

Comment: @GordonDavisson The double quotes for a value that is expected to be a (single) string is universal. The question was about `echo` not display the `-e` which apparently it did consume as an option. I.e. it was about variable expansion / argument passing and not text formatting  (I just used those examples for given context to illustrate the point), All that said *"none of this is portable"* does not sound right as much as notes about `echo` versions and hint regarding `printf` as such are correct (generally, specifically the question again is bash and apparently its builtin echo).